# How do I return a value from collection inside a Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How do I get my values in the `textarea` back on `OnPostSave`. The List below is showing a count of 0 and no property of "val" even though its displaying the correct values.

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public List<number> Numbers { get; set; }        

public class number
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}
```

In the cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Numbers)
{
    <textarea asp-for="@item.val" style="width:100%">@item.val</textarea>
}
```

[image]

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostSave()
{
    foreach (var _nums in Numbers)
    {
        var amt = _nums.val;
    }
    return Page();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What value do you want see at `Numbers`?

Comment: Do you want to get 1 and 2 or the string you write in the  textarea ?

Comment: You can use a sequential index or an explicit index for binding collections in ASP.NET Core: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get the value of 1 and 2, you can try the below code:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        <textarea asp-for="@Model.Numbers[@i].val" style="width:100%" >@Model.Numbers[@i].val</textarea>        

    }
```

result:

[image]